# Storing from wildcard input path

Tags: apache-pig

I’m having issues using wildcard input paths in Pig.

If I run the following commands:

```
A = load ‘/something/*.csv’ using PigStorage(‘,’)
dump A;
```

I see the output from all csv files in the something folder printed to my console after the job is run.

If, however, I run a store instead:

```
A = load ‘/something/*.csv’ using PigStorage(‘,’)
store A into ‘somedestination’;
```

The job fails with the following error message:

```
Input(s):
Failed to read data from “/something/*.csv”
```

It looks like the store is attempting to load from the literal path instead of globbing using the wildcard, but if that’s the case then why does it work during the dump? Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: can you pls paste whole output when it fails to read data in case of store? My guess is it has nothing to do with STORE or globbing, but script might be failing cause of other issue, but still you are seeing "failed to read data from /something/*.csv"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have the permission to write to that folder.
The dump essentially writes to the tmp folder (or another folder if the configuration is different) and then prints that to the screen.

Do a dump. Look at the log. It should say something like:

```
Input(s):
Successfully read 0 records from: "‘/something/*.csv’"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "file:/tmp/temp1865628879/tmp-1573237939"
```

Then next time try and store to the folder that you saw when you did the dump. If that works fine, then you have a permissions problem.